# What is the correct syntax to insert a table inside a paragraph using Pandoc's JSON AST?

Tags: json, abstract-syntax-tree, pandoc

I use Pandoc for technical reporting and modified the Python pandocfilters package example [metavars.py](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters/blob/master/examples/metavars.py) to provide variable substitution. `%{test}` in the Markdown gets substituted with the value of `test` in the YAML metadata. Works great!

It works with both single line and "block" style YAML.

I'd like to do the same but rather than dropping in a block of text drop in a Markdown formatted table. Here's my minimal test document (`example.md`):

```
---
test: |-
    | a |
    |---|
    | 1 |
block: |-
    This Markdown _formatted_ a block \
    of YAML \
    text.
...

After this paragraph you should see a block:

%{block}

After this paragraph you should see a table:

%{test}
```

You can see my modified `metavars.py` at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rbdixon/f8072fc4db5605c3d92d).

If you comment out the `%{test}` text and run it you'll see correct output:

```
$ pandoc -t json example.md  | ./metavars.py | pandoc -f json -t plain
After this paragraph you should see a block:

This Markdown _formatted_ a block
of YAML
text.

After this paragraph you should see a table:
```

When I uncomment `%{test}` I end up with an error and no backtrace:

```
$ pandoc -t json example.md  | ./metavars.py | pandoc -f json -t plain

test -> [[], [{u'c': [], u't': u'AlignDefault'}], [0.0], [[{u'c':
[{u'c': u'a', u't': u'Str'}], u't': u'Plain'}]], [[[{u'c': 
[{u'c': u'1', u't': u'Str'}], u't': u'Plain'}]]]]

pandoc: Error in $[3][0]: expected Object, encountered Array
```

I'm stuck here! My assumption is that I've built an valid JSON document that which is invalid Pandoc AST. I can't find documentation on the Pandoc AST and when I compare what I've generated to manually constructed Markdown converted to AST I'm not seeing the difference.

This is what I *want* to get as a result:

```
$ pandoc -t json example.md  | ./metavars.py | pandoc -f json -t plain
After this paragraph you should see a block:

This Markdown _formatted_ a block
of YAML
text.

After this paragraph you should see a table:

  a
  ---
  1
```

I'm really close, from a diff basis:

- [Correct AST output](https://gist.github.com/f9ad33c1c0f1789583e4)
- [What I get now](https://gist.github.com/33683a88f0fcae2f173d)
- [Diff](https://gist.github.com/26624c97b982d298ba08)

Any suggestions on what to emit to get my Table inserted within the Para? I'm hoping I'm not boxed into a situation where I can't do that.

Comment: The Pandoc AST definition is written in Haskell (like all of pandoc) and in [its own repository](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L196)... From your diff the problem appears obvious, right? You're emitting a `Para` instead of a `Table`.. btw, I think you'd be better of using a preprocessor than a filter, see e.g. [this blog post](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/).

Comment: I'll research using a preprocessor. Thank you for the deep link into the source. Yeah, I see the diff. :) If there is a valid syntax to do what I'd like to from a filter that would be best since I've got one already. Perhaps there isn't. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your comments got me thinking... why not just "look down" in the paragraph to see if it contains nested elements that would be replaced? Here's an [updated version](https://gist.github.com/bbbd7364ed7ea1f5f2a9) of `metavars.py` that does what I intended. Thank you for your help @mb21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As inspired by @mb21's comments to my question:

Table elements are a peer to Para elements in the AST so nesting a Table within a Para is prohibited. The best way to tackle this problem is to work *up* a level in the AST. For each Para element in the AST scan to see if it contains a nested element which then contains a variable (`%{test}`, for example) that will be replaced by a Table. If so then replace the entire Para element with the Table.

Here is an updated version of [metavars.py](https://gist.github.com/bbbd7364ed7ea1f5f2a9) which works as expected.

Again... thanks to @mb21 for the assist.